# What would take longer to execute in a million row table LIMIT 37,22 or LIMIT 100037,22

Tags: mysql

In mysql: In a table of a million rows which would take longer `LIMIT 37,22` or `LIMIT 100037,22`?

Comment: `LIMIT 100037,22` for sure as MySQL need to fetchs 100037 + 22 records, to remove 100037 again to show the 22 records.   And most likely MySQL also needs to store that amount it in a (disk) temporary table to make matters worse.

Comment: Also this question is pretty much a duplication [Mysql large limit offsets](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Mysql+large+limit+offsets)

Comment: Thank you raymond. I am very new both to sql and to stackoverflow so please bear that in mind when pointing out that the questions is a duplicate

Answer (score 2):

I assume you mean querying 22 rows with low vs. high offset.

You can see benchmarks [here](https://www.eversql.com/faster-pagination-in-mysql-why-order-by-with-limit-and-offset-is-slow/)

When offset has high value, queries become slow because the DB has to access all rows until the offset. Better use `where` than offset when possible.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, indeed that is exactly what I was after